# Retrieve the reset value of RegInit

Tags: chisel, rocket-chip

Is there a way to get the reset value of a `RegInit` by probing members of the type that is produces? I can see that a RegInit will return the type (e.g. `UInt`). For example I will have a register which I want to be controlled via a `regmap`

```scala
val myRWReg = RegInit(3.U(10.W))

// ...

node.regmap(
  0x0 -> Seq(RegField(10.W, myRWReg,
               RegFieldDesc("myRWReg", "A RW Register.", reset = myRWReg.init)))
)
```

`.init` is not an accessible member, but is shown here to imply it's what I'm looking for.

Is there a way to do this so that anytime a `RegFieldDesc` is used the reset description can match the hardware without having to keep another variable?

A workaround/solution is to make `3.U` in my example a `val` that is changed based on any parameters and simply pass that, but wasn't sure if there was something else that could be used.

Comment: That sounds like a useful feature but does not exist. I think the extra `val` is the best option here.

Comment: Ok fair enough. Thanks for the feedback! Would it be helpful to submit an enhancement request on the github repo?

Comment: Yes, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up coming up with something that may be useful for others. One of the things I wanted to also be able to do was not have to explicitly declare a `Reg`. I wanted this to be inferred by the connection. For example, I have a SW register that is driving an 8bit "port" on a `Bundle`. I could make a `Reg` but then I need to keep up with the size if it changes based on parameters.

```scala
object WavRWReg{
  
  def apply[T <: Data](connection : T, reset: T, name: String, desc: String = ""): RegField = {
    //val reg = RegInit(reset)
    val reg = RegInit(connection.cloneType, reset)
    
    reg.suggestName("swi_" + name)
    
    connection := reg
    
    //litValue returns the Bigint value
    val rf = RegField(reg.getWidth, reg.asUInt, RegFieldDesc(name, desc, access=RegFieldAccessType.RW , reset=Some(reset.litValue)))
    rf
  }
}
```

So this creates the `Reginit` to the specified reset val, and the width is inferred from the connection type. The reset value is also sent to the `RegFieldDesc` so I don't have to manually keep up with it in two places, keeping down on errors.

Answer (score 0):

you may also be interested in `DescribedReg`:
https://github.com/chipsalliance/rocket-chip/blob/30e38e83a1a427bba5441afad83bde947fa75542/src/main/scala/regmapper/DescribedReg.scala#L7

It both builds the register and its description at the same time.
An example usage:
https://github.com/chipsalliance/rocket-chip/blob/30e38e83a1a427bba5441afad83bde947fa75542/src/main/scala/tile/BusErrorUnit.scala#L58